# Agrega y quitar Clase con jQuery o JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

Estoy tratando de agregar una clase a un elemento, pero necesito que la clase se agregue solo cuando le den click a un label, y asi se pueda desplegar el ul="desplegable-1", dentro de esa otra hay otro ul="desplegable-2" que cuando se le de clic le active una clase y si se le da clic otra ves se le quite. De igual manera si se le da clic algun objeto de la lista lo llevara a la pagina pero seguira marcado y desplegado el ul del cual se haya seleccionado.

IMPORTANTE: Si le doy clic a un elemento se agrega la clase, y si le vuelvo a dar click a ese elemento se tiene que remover esa clase y asi sucesivamente. Al estar seleccionado algun de ello actualizara la pagina y se seguira viendo desplegado y marcado el seleccionado.

```js
$("label.title-item").click(function() {
    $(".desplegable-1").addClass("active-desp");
});

$("label.title-sub").click(function() {
    $(".desplegable-2").addClass("active-desp2");
});
```

```css
.desplegable-1,.desplegable-2 {
    display:none;
}

.active-desp, .active-desp2{
    display:block;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="A"/>
    <label for="D" class="title-item">Titulo 3</label>                
    <ul class="desplegable-1">                    
        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#" class="sub-title-item">Sub titulo 1</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#">Sub titulo 2</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li-1">
                 <div class="sub-item">
              <input type="checkbox" id="A-A"/>
              <label for="A-A" class="title-sub">Lista de Sub titulos</label>       
              <ul class="desplegable-2">
                  <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 1</a></li>
                  <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 2</a></li>
                  <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 3</a></li>
                  <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 4</a></li>                                                        
              </ul>
               </div> 
             </li>                                              
            <li class="sub-li"><a href="#">Sub titulo 3</a></li>                     
                        </li>                  
      </ul>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="B"/>
    <label for="D" class="title-item">Titulo 2</label>                
        <ul class="desplegable-1">                    
           <li class="sub-li"><a href="#" class="sub-title-item">Sub titulo 1</a></li>
           <li class="sub-li"><a href="#">Sub titulo 2</a></li>
           <li class="sub-li-1">
                <div class="sub-item">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="B-A"/>
                    <label for="B-A" class="title-sub">Lista de Sub titulos</label>       
                      <ul class="desplegable-2">
                          <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 1</a></li>
                          <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 2</a></li>
                          <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 3</a></li>
                          <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 4</a></li>                                                        
                        </ul>
                </div> 
             </li>                                              
             <li class="sub-li"><a href="#">Subtitulo3</a></li>                     
                        </li>                  
      </ul>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="B"/>
    <label for="D" class="title-item">Titulo 1</label>                
    <ul class="desplegable-1">                    
        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#" class="sub-title-item">Sub titulo 1</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#">Sub titulo 2</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li-1">
              <div class="sub-item">
              <input type="checkbox" id="B-A"/>
              <label for="B-A" class="title-sub">Lista de Sub titulos</label>       
              <ul class="desplegable-2">
                <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 1</a></li>
                <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 2</a></li>
                <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 3</a></li>
                <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 4</a></li>                                                          
             </ul>
            </div> 
            </li>                                               
            <li class="sub-li"><a href="#">Sub titulo 3</a> 
           </li>                     
            </li>                  
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: busca `toggle class jquery` en google y veras varios ejemplo de lo que deseas!

Comment: el toggle class me abre las 3 listas a la vez

Comment: En vez de agregar clases, es mejor actuar directamente con **display: none** o **display:block**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hacer clic en un título, la función actual agrega o quita la clase a todos los elementos que tengan clase ".desplegable-1" y no solo al que debería, pero vamos por partes:

Revisando tu código, se debe hacer clic en una etiqueta y que se despliegue el siguiente elemento:

```
<label for="D" class="title-item">Titulo 3</label>                
<ul class="desplegable-1">
```

Y lo mismo para los subtítulos:

```
<label for="A-A" class="title-sub">Lista de Sub titulos</label>       
<ul class="desplegable-2">
```

Con esto, tomas el elemento que recibió clic con `$(this)` y seleccionas el siguiente con la clase deseada, usando [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) y, como ya te dijeron en comentarios, puedes hacer uso del método [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) para agregar o quitar la clase especificada.

```js
$("label.title-item").click(function() {
    // Buscar el siguiente elemento por clase
    $(this).next(".desplegable-1").toggleClass("active-desp");
});

$("label.title-sub").click(function() {
    // Buscar el siguiente elemento por clase
    $(this).next(".desplegable-2").toggleClass("active-desp2");
});
```

```css
.desplegable-1,.desplegable-2 {
    display:none;
}

.active-desp, .active-desp2{
    display:block;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="A"/>
                    <label for="D" class="title-item">Titulo 3</label>                
                    <ul class="desplegable-1">                    
                        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#" class="sub-title-item">Sub titulo 1</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#">Sub titulo 2</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-li-1">
                            <div class="sub-item">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="A-A"/>
                                <label for="A-A" class="title-sub">Lista de Sub titulos</label>       
                                <ul class="desplegable-2">
                                    <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 1</a></li>
                                    <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 2</a></li>
                                    <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 3</a></li>
                                    <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 4</a></li>                                                          
                                </ul>
                                </div> 
                        </li>                                               
                        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#">Sub titulo 3</a></li>                     
                        </li>                  
                    </ul>
</div>
<div class="item">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="B"/>
                    <label for="D" class="title-item">Titulo 2</label>                
                    <ul class="desplegable-1">                    
                        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#" class="sub-title-item">Sub titulo 1</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#">Sub titulo 2</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-li-1">
                            <div class="sub-item">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="B-A"/>
                                <label for="B-A" class="title-sub">Lista de Sub titulos</label>       
                                <ul class="desplegable-2">
                                    <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 1</a></li>
                                    <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 2</a></li>
                                    <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 3</a></li>
                                    <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 4</a></li>                                                          
                                </ul>
                                </div> 
                        </li>                                               
                        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#">Subtitulo3</a></li>                     
                        </li>                  
                    </ul>
</div>
<div class="item">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="B"/>
                    <label for="D" class="title-item">Titulo 1</label>                
                    <ul class="desplegable-1">                    
                        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#" class="sub-title-item">Sub titulo 1</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#">Sub titulo 2</a></li>
                        <li class="sub-li-1">
                            <div class="sub-item">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="B-A"/>
                                <label for="B-A" class="title-sub">Lista de Sub titulos</label>       
                                <ul class="desplegable-2">
                                    <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 1</a></li>
                                    <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 2</a></li>
                                    <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 3</a></li>
                                    <li class="sub-li-2"><a href="#" class="sub-item-2">Lista 4</a></li>                                                          
                                </ul>
                                </div> 
                        </li>                                               
                        <li class="sub-li"><a href="#">Sub titulo 3</a></li>                     
                        </li>                  
                    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me sirvió, una consulta y si dentro de los li se selecciona un elemento lo redirige como puedo hacer para que al recargar la pagina siga desplegado y marcado el elemento seleccionado?

Comment: Da la respuesta por aceptada o por lo menos puntuala con la flecha hacia arriba, ayuda a indicar que esta pregunta se ha respondido.

Answer (score 0):

Observo tu código y te doy algunas recomendaciones, primero para darle eventos (click, change.. etc) te sugiero que no uses la clase de css, esto porque después no vas a poder reutilizar las clases, además que si llegas a hacerlo (reutilizar clases) le vas a dar comportamientos no adecuados a otros elementos.
Como sugerencia te recomiendo usar el id para manejar los eventos de los elementos html por ejemplo:

```
//en html
//<ul id="desplegable-1"> ..etc..

$("#desplegable-1").click(function(){
    //Ejecuta aca tu codigo, fijate que estamos usando el id del elemento
})
```

Respondiendo a tu pregunta `Agrega y quitar Clase con jQuery o JS`
te recomiendo crear una clases css:

```
//En tu css
.d-none {
   display:none;
 }
 //En tu js
 $("#desplegable-1).click(function(){
    //Ejecuta aca tu codigo, fijate que estamos usando el id del elemento
    $("#Ejemplo").addClass("d-none")//Esto ocultaria el elemento
    //En caso de que quieras mostrarlo 
    $("#Ejemplo").removeClass("d-none")
    //Podrias incluso ir mas alla y comprobar si tiene la clase
    if($("Ejemplo").hasClass("d-none")){
       //comprueba que el elemento tenga la clase d-none para removerla
       $("#Ejemplo").removeClass("d-none")
    }
 })
```

con eso deberia bastar, ahora bien veo que usas dos clases.. una para dar `display:block;` y otra para dar `display:none;`.Mi recomendacion es que uses primero `removeClass` y luego `addClass` de lo contrario puede que se acumulen las clases en tu elemento por cada click al final quedaria asi por ejemplo

```
<label id="ejemplo" class="d-none d-block ">este es un ejemplo</label>
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda